# Conditional redirect with domain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I would like to make a redirect in Apache with a domain based rule. For example

If a user access to the page from `example.com` or another related page (`example.com/another-url/`), then redirect to `example.com/page.html`. Else, show the normal page.

I write in the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^example.com
    RewriteRule .* /page.html [R=302,L]    
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "access to the page from `example.com`" - presumably you mean a request made **to** `example.com`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have multiple domains on this account?

To redirect either `example.com/` or `example.com/another-url/` to `example.com/page.html` then you can do something like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(|another-url/)$ /page.html [R=302,L]
```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the host being requested. The pattern `^(|another-url/)$` matches either an empty URL-path (ie. the document root) or `another-url/` (less the directory prefix).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^one.domain.com
> RewriteRule .* /page.html [R=302,L]
> ```

This would have redirected *everything* to `/page.html`. The problems with your original directives...

- `REMOTE_ADDR` is the client IP address making the request, not the *host* being requested.
- The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex. So, in the above it matches when the `REMOTE_ADDR` is *not* `example.com`. (Always true.)
- The `.*` `RewriteRule` pattern matches *every* URL!